# How to bring on second condition input form when selected dropdown item in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

**Task:**

To create a dropdown list for option values:"Name1...Name2...Name3...Others". Hence, when a user were to click on the option 'Others', it will generate an additional form fields for the user to enter and they are: "Name, Rego No., Address".

**What has been done:**

I have created the following dropdown list as shown:

```
<p>
<!--Input select box with options: Name1...Name2...Name3...Others-->
<select name ="Name" id="NameDetails">
<option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Name..</option>
<option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
<option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
<option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
<option value = "Others"> Others</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Hence, the dropdown list is able to be shown. Furthermore, I have also created the html version for the 3 additional fields as shown below:

```
<p>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name" title="Name" class="defaultValue required" tabindex="7" />
<div id="searchNameResultsContainer"></div>
<div id="errorSearchNameResultsContainer" class="rounded errorSearchResultsContainer yui-ac-container"></div>
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="Rego No." id="Rego No." value="Reg No." title="Reg No." class="leftCol defaultValue required validateInput formatNumber" tabindex="8" />
</p>
....(Identical for "Address" field)
```

**Issue:**
At this point, I am stuck at how to call the additional 3 fields when users select 'Others' from the dropdown list. I have tried to use the "if..else" condition but am stuck when I tried to input the above code within if statement.

Hence, could anyone please help? Thanks.

**code edit:**

```
<div>
<p>
<!--Input selectbox with options: Name1...Name2...Name3...Others-->
<select name ="Name" id="NameDetails" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
<option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
<option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
<option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
<option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
<option value = "Others"> Others</option>
</select>
</p>

<!-- Set Conditional check, if user clicks Others, direct to input field: Name,  Registration Number, Address-->

<div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">
<p>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name"  title="Name" class="defaultValue required" tabindex="7" />
<div id="searchNameResultsContainer"></div>
<div id="errorNameCompanyResultsContainer" class="rounded errorSearchResultsContainer yui-ac-container"></div>
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="RegistrationNum" id="RegistrationNum" value="Registration Num" title="Registration Num" class="leftCol defaultValue required validateInput formatNumber" tabindex="8" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" value="Address" title="Address" class="defaultValue required signupinput_txt" tabindex="9" />
<div id="searchAddressResultsContainer" class="hide searchResultsContainer"></div>
<div id="errorSearchAddressResultsContainer" class="rounded errorSearchResultsContainer yui-ac-container"></div>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function val(x)
{
    if (x =="Others" )
    {
            document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display ="block";
    }else
    {
            document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript or jquery.

Just wrap your additional form elements under `div` and give it id e.g `other_ele` and also made that div `display:none` by default using css.

Just try that code below i have used javascript for this

First on your select tag use `onchange` like:

```
<select name ="Name" id="NameDetails" onchange="return val(this.value);">
```

This onchange will call val function

And writ your script like that

```
<script>
function val(x)
{
    if(x == "Others")
    {
        document.getElementById("other_ele").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("other_ele").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Note `other_ele` is id of your div in which you have wrapped your additional form elements.

Hope this will work for you

Comment: I have tried your method but it is not displaying. Just need to confirm that when I set about the additional form element<div></div>. Do I set it outside of the existing <div></div> where the select option list is or can I set together with the existing <div></div>

Comment: No you have to wrap your this code under div and give that div id

<p>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name" title="Name" class="defaultValue required" tabindex="7" />
<div id="searchNameResultsContainer"></div>
<div id="errorSearchNameResultsContainer" class="rounded errorSearchResultsContainer yui-ac-container"></div>
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="Rego No." id="Rego No." value="Reg No." title="Reg No." class="leftCol defaultValue required validateInput formatNumber" tabindex="8" />
</p>

If you still have any problem please let me know

Comment: you have given id in wrong manner

<div id - "extradiv" style ="display:none">

Just replace it with 

<div id="extradiv" style ="display:none">

Comment: I have modified the above code such that there are 2 <div> extensions and within the `function val(x)` method is that it will call either one of the 2 <div> extensions. However, at this point, when I click "Others", it will show one of the <div> but when I click either one of the "Name1".."Name3" after I have clicked "Others", it will show the prv<div> extension plus the new <div>. How is it possible to show only either 1 ?

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery, put those 3 extra field in a div with id #extradiv and set its style as display:none to keep is hidden on load.

```
 <div id="extradiv" style="display:none">
 <!-- 3 extra fields -->
 </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#NameDetails').on('change',function(){
     $('#extradiv").hide();
     var changeVal = $("#NameDetails").val();
     if(changeVal == "Others){
     $("#extradiv").show();
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: So I don't include it in any if else statement?

Comment: not required, make sure you have a jquery library included.

Comment: Sorry but I need to ask what does the  following code of line means: `$('#NameDetails').on('change',function(){
     $('#extradiv").hide();
     var changeVal = $("#NameDetails").val();
     if(changeVal == "Others){
     $("#extradiv").show();
     });
     `

Comment: it is a change event, when you select any value from dropdown it will get trigger, fetch the value of selected dropdown. if it matched "Others" It will show the 3 extra fields otherwise , it will be kept hidden.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and update on how it is going